# Why did removing "else" without changing logic cut my runtime in half?

Tags: swift, algorithm, loops, if-statement

After solving this problem on LeetCode: https://leetcode.com/problems/count-and-say/
my first solution took 16ms. By removing an else statement, without (as far as I can tell) changing the logic in any way, the runtime went down to 8ms.

It went from beating 24.31% of swift submissions to beating 93.75%.

Can anyone explain why? It feels to me like they should be the same.

```
func countAndSay(_ n: Int) -> String {
    if n == 1 {
        return "1"
    }

    var output = ""
    let previous = countAndSay(n-1)

    var count = 0
    var lastChar = Character("0")

    for (n, c) in previous.enumerated() {           
        if n == 0 {
            lastChar = c
            count = 1
        } else {
            if c == lastChar {
                count += 1
            } else {
                output += "\(count)\(lastChar)"
                count = 1
                lastChar = c
            }
        }
    }

    output += "\(count)\(lastChar)"

    return output
}
```

I changed the for loop to this and cut the time in half:

```
for (n, c) in previous.enumerated() {
    if n == 0 {
        lastChar = c
        count = 1
        continue
    }

    if c == lastChar {
        count += 1
    } else {
        output += "\(count)\(lastChar)"
        count = 1
        lastChar = c
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess; I don't know anything about how the Swift compiler generates code. The explicit continue produces a branch that returns to the top of the loop, while the `else` produces a branch that skips to the end of the loop, which would be *another* branch back to the top. Aside from eliminating an extra branch instruction, there could be cache implications for not having to load extra code to reach the end of the loop.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Have you reproduced it on your own system? How did you test it?

Comment: Submitted them as different solutions to LeetCode, so it’s compiling on their end not in Xcode.